# Flexbox to fill out row and determine the number of children per row

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have a bunch of boxes in a container. I don't know how many boxes fit onto a row, the bigger your screen is the more boxes there should be. However I want each row to be fully filled and the boxes resized (within 100px to 150px) to ensure that each row is filled.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssxu5moy/11/

```
.container2 {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    background: blue;
    align-self: stretch;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 150px;
}

<div class="container2">
    <div class="box box1">
    </div>
    <div class="box box2">
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
    </div>
</div>
```

I already did this in javascript and it works fine, but I thought about changing to flexbox to be simpler, but I'm having difficulty getting it working. Is this even possible in flexbox?

Comment: Is there any flexibility to the 100-150px box size? How is the row supposed to fill if only one box wraps to the next row?

Comment: @Michael_B yes you're right there's a contradiction in what I'm asking for. I would like for all the boxes to be the same size, the stretching should only be for the boxes in the initial rows, I would like the final row boxes to have the same size as all the rest of the boxes.

Comment: @Michael_B I don't think OP does. He wants the boxes in the second row to be the same width as the boxes in the first row - even as they grow and shrink. So if there are 5 boxes on top with a width of `100px`, and the second has 2 boxes, those boxes should be `100px`, but if the screen gets larger and the top row now has 6 boxes that have a width of `150px`, that last row with one box, the box should have a width of `150px`. There's really no way for `flexbox` to achieve this natively. As there is a flexible width as the screen resizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah! You can do that. The `max-width` is making the boxes stop at `150px` which appears not what you want as you want each box to fill the remaining space in the row after the wrap right?

Here's an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/ssxu5moy/12/

The only thing I changed in your CSS was the `min-width` and `max-width` to the flex property:

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    background: blue;
    align-self: stretch;
    flex:1 0 100px;
}
```

If I understood your question, this should be what you're looking for. *Caveat:* `flex` property needs browser prefix.

EDIT: here's some light reading on the `flex` property shorthand:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

In the event the link is gone:
This is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis (respectively).

Comment: Except the question says each box must be between 100px and 150px. This answer doesn't adhere to that.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how the rows could be fully filled if the `max-size` is restricted. That's why I prefaced my answer with an assumption.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to keep the final row boxes the same size as the rest of the boxes (make it not stretch as much)?

Comment: I checked this answer because it answers the question as initially posed, but I would really appreciate it if you could help me with the final row problem (or let me know if it's impossible).

Comment: I think your working JS is the only way this can happen, because you can actively get the width of the boxes in the first row and set all the boxes to same size.

Comment: Thanks for your help!