# Is it possible to images position like this (Possibly without float)?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I am trying to position images in the following way starting from **Left to Right** and also keep it in the center of the screen:

[image]
However, I cannot get it to do that instead the last image always appears in the center of the row like in the image below:

[image]

Is there a way to be able to display it like that but also keep it in the **CENTER** of the screen?

I am using **display: inline-block** in **#gallery > div**

**CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/m9xuj8aa/**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
            <header>
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <nav class="cl-effect-21">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html" class="scroll">
                                <span data-hover="Home">Home</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about" class="scroll">
                                <span data-hover="About Us">About Us</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#services" class="scroll">
                                <span data-hover="Services">Services</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Portfolio.html" class="scroll">
                                <span data-hover="Portfolio">Portfolio</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#testimonials" class="scroll">
                                <span data-hover="Testimonials">Testimonials</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Contact.html" class="scroll active">
                                <span data-hover="Contact Us">Contact Us</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>


            <div class="portfolio clearfix">
                <div id="gallery">
                    <div id="img-wrapper">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/1.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/1.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="img-wrapper">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/2.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/2.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="img-wrapper">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/3.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/3.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="img-wrapper">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/4.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/4.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="img-wrapper">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/5.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/5.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="img-wrapper">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/6.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/6.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="img-wrapper">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/7.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/7.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="img-wrapper">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/8.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/8.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="img-wrapper" class="last">
                        <a href="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/9.jpg">
                            <img src="assets/images/DesiGotTalent3/9.jpg" alt="">
                            <div id="overlay">
                                <h1 class="fa fa-search"></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="social">
                <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-vimeo"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-youtube"></span>
            </div>

            <h3>&copy; 2016 Dinesh Joshi Photography</h3>
        </footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
/** External Stylesheet **/
* { margin: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
}

footer, .push { 
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}

footer {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#social {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#social span {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    margin: 0px 3px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    width: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    background: #D4AF37;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


/** Header **/
header {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0px 8px;
}

nav a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* Effect 21: borders slight translate */
.cl-effect-21 a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s;
}

.cl-effect-21 a::before,
.cl-effect-21 a::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.2px;
    background: #D4AF37;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.active {
    border-top: 1.2px solid #D4A347;
    border-bottom: 1.2px solid #D4A347;
}

.cl-effect-21 a::before {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.cl-effect-21 a::after {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
.cl-effect-21 a:hover::before,
.cl-effect-21 a:focus::before,
.cl-effect-21 a:hover::after,
.cl-effect-21 a:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

/* End of external stylesheet */
.portfolio {
                width: 100%;
                margin:0 auto;
            }

            #gallery {
                width: 100%;
                margin:0 auto;
                padding: 0px 10px;
                display: table;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #gallery img {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }

            #gallery > div {
        width: 150px;
        height: 140px;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
        background-color:black;
        margin: 5px;
            }

            #gallery a div {
                position:absolute;
                width: 150px;
                margin:0 auto;
                text-align: center;
                top: 0;
                right:0;
                left:0;
                bottom:0;
                z-index: 1;
                transform: translate(-110%, 0);
                -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        display:none;
            }

            #gallery a:hover #overlay {
                background-color:rgba(212, 175, 55, .3);
                transform: translate(0,0);
            }

            #gallery div:nth-of-type(9) {
                text-align: left;
            }

            #gallery h1 {
                font-size: 20px;
                color:white;
                margin:3.6em 0px;
            }

            .clearfix {
                clear: both;
            }
```

Comment: Huh, I have seen the *exact same question* an hour ago but you've deleted it. Why did you repost the question?

Comment: **Never** have 2 identical IDs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox to fill out row and determine the number of children per row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774178/flexbox-to-fill-out-row-and-determine-the-number-of-children-per-row)

Comment: OK no, it's actually the *question* that's doing what you want in link above, not the answer.

Comment: Is the amount of items to be in the layout going to stay the same? Will it always be known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems the images were of different sizes and therefore weren't able to float from left to right properly.

Fixed by adding explicit height to the images

Answer (score 0):

You could put the whole 4 images thing in a container, then in that container you can initialize the photos with a certain amount of pixels from eachother, then it should be done!

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox her's an update to your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kriddy800/3evmfvog/3/) I've removed the display table on #gallery added in display flex (default is row) and added a wrap

```
#gallery {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: 100%;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding: 0px 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

**EDIT#1**

I've updated the fiddle link, it's a bit of a dirty fix but hopefully it will spark some ideas.  The only thing to note is that if you're looking for responsive design you are going to have to execute the logic on a window resize.  Which is why I don't think this is the perfect solution.

Comment: Isn't that doing a similar thing to Float? It partially what I want, but the entire set of images are not in the centre of the screen, they are more to the left. What I want is everything centred and the last image (on the third row) to start on the left